# How can I split a long string using regex (\.\s) ignoring a few cases

Tags: regex, dart, regex-lookarounds

For ex I have this sentence

```
Hello. Hello.bye. 125. 000. 182.000. U. S. A.
```

I want it to split it in a list of String and I am using regex `"\.\s"` for it and it looks like this below.

```
Hello
Hello.bye
125
000
182.000
U
S
A
```

But I want to add a condition where if there is a digit or a capital alphabet before the `\.\s` it should not split from there. For ex in the above case it looks like this below:

```
Hello
Hello.bye
125. 000
182.000
U. S. A.
```

I have tried using a positive look behind conditional but it's not working. Here is what I am doing

```
(?(?<!([A-Z]|[0-9]))(\.\s))
```

Comment: Sometimes, it's easier to specify the parts you want to keep, rather than the parts you want to throw away.  Does that help?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I learned regex just yesterday it would be easier to understand if you provide some code that can help.

Comment: Please share the code with a single example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for matching the parts you want to match:

```bash
\d+\.(?:\s*\d+)?|[A-Z]+(?:\.\s*[A-Z])+|\w[\w.]+?(?=\.\s)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YJ4Vwp/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\d+\.(?:\s*\d+)?`: Match digits separated with dot and 0+ whitespaces
- `|`: OR
- `[A-Z]+(?:\.\s*[A-Z])+`: Match uppercase strings separated with dot and 0+ whitespaces
- `|`: OR
- `\w[\w.]+?(?=\.\s)`: Match any other test that start with a word char and must have dot and whitespace as delimiter.

---

For splitting following regex would work but still a match should be preferred:

```bash
(?<![A-Z]|[1-9](?=\.\s\d))\.\s
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/YJ4Vwp/2)